# Javascript - How to save a reference to "this" for access in named function callback using prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having problems getting a reference to a javascript object implemented with the
prototype pattern within a callback. The callback is from a 3rd party component 
I utilize within my object. The 3rd party object connects to a message bus.

The following pseudo code shows how I started (The real code for this is working)

```
var mb = require('MsgBus')

TestClass = function() {
  this.messagebus = new mb.MsgBus();
  this.messagebus.connect(function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log("Error connecting");
      else
        console.log("Connected");
  });
}
```

But then I wanted to have it automatically retry connecting if the callback reports
 an error. I cannot just put another line if the if(err) block that
 says "this.messagebus.connection" because I would have to add another anonymous
 method for that connect callback and it would just go on and on. So, I want to 
 split out the callback logic to a named function like this

```
var mb = require('MsgBus')

TestClass = function() {
  this.messagebus = new mb.MsgBus();
  this.messagebus.connect(msgBusConnectCallback); 
}

function msgBusConnectCallback(err) {
      if(err)
        this???.messagebus.connect(msgBusConnectCallback);
      else
        console.log("Connected");
  });
}
```

The callback function gets called, but I cannot figure out how to get a reference 
to the object to call connect again. I've also tried to make the callback a 
prototype function of the object, still no reference. I cannot create a variable
in the global scope to maintain "this" because the user of this class may 
create multiple instances of the class. I am fairly new to JavaScript so I don't 
know if I'm just missing something or if I need to take a different approach 
altogether. I would appreciate any help and/or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer, the correct syntax is
    this.messagebus.connect(msgBusConnectCallback.bind(this));

Answer (score 3):

```
this.messagebus.connect.apply(this, [msgBusConnectCallback]);
```

Comment: You have it wrong. It's `msgBusConnectCallback.apply(this)`

Comment: The solution from slebetman works - within the callback this now points to my object. However, the err parameter to the callback is always undefined, even when it shouldn't be. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pathfinder `msgBusConnectCallback.apply(this, [err])`

Comment: Adding the [err] causes a javascript ReferenceError: err is not defined (In the object "constructor")

Comment: @Pathfinder `var self = this; this.messagebus.connect(function (err) { msgBusConnectCallback.apply(self, [err])});`